# Is it possible to produce stand alone haskell executable

Tags: linux, haskell, executable, ghc

Is there any way to produce stand alone haskell executable to run on different linux machines assuming the architecture is similar?

Sorry I should have been clearer. The other machines might not have ghc installed on them - a bit like pyinstaller for python is what I was looking for?

Comment: is this http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/03/shelly-for-shell-scripts what you are looking for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the flags `-static -optl-pthread -optl-static` to avoid dynamically linked dependencies when compiling a Haskell project. This should help you run the compiled executable on two linux machines that do not have the exact same library versions.

Comment: I've never had luck with ghc and static linking so I am curious how well this works out for you (and shang).  For example, on Fedora you obvioulsy need the static libraries (`yum install glibc-static`) but there is still an issue with the RTS calling dlopen.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible.  Just like with gcc-produced binaries, you can copy them between systems assuming the dynamic libraries and platforms match.

In practice, that's a slightly higher bar than GCC binaries because GHC will dynamically link more libraries by default (ex: libgmp, unless you build GHC using integer-simple).